# jquery change image path

Tags: jquery, function, time, image, attr

I've had to use a div with an image to cover the page due to issues with getting the background to stretch across the entire page in different browsers.

What I'm trying to do is to get this image to change dependent on the time of day. I had it working fine when I was using the more conventional background-image property in CSS, but I'm having problems translating it over to change the src attribute of the image.

The id of the image is #bg. I'm probably making a syntactical error, but any help would be great, thanks!

```
$('document').ready(function(){

 var hours = getDayTime(new Date().getHours());

if (hours > 20 || hours < 5) {
    $('#page-background > img').prop('src', 'backgrounds/night.jpg')
}    

else if (hours > 17) {
    $('#page-background > img').prop('src', 'backgrounds/dusk.jpg')
}    

else if (hours > 8) {
    $('#page-background > img').prop('src', 'backgrounds/day.jpg')
}

else { 
    $('#page-background > img').prop('src', 'backgrounds/dawn.jpg')
}
});


<div id="page-background"><img src="backgrounds/day.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" alt="" id="bg" /></div>
```

Comment: where hours variable defined? can you put your whole page?

Comment: I've added the relevant bits of HTML now as well, thanks.

Comment: @EmilyTwist where is `hours` defined ? any errors ?

Comment: @ManseUK I've got it as: `code` $('document').ready(function(){
          var hours = getDayTime(new Date().getHours());
 
                 if (hours > 20 || hours < 5) {
                 $('#page-background > img').prop('src',      'backgrounds/night.jpg')
    }   `code`                                                                  is that right?

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#bg img').attr('src', 'backgrounds/night.jpg')
```

should just be

```
$('#bg').prop('src', 'backgrounds/night.jpg')
```

As you specified the `id` of the image already there is no need to include the `img`. And [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) is preferred to `attr()` as of jQuery 1.6

Comment: I've added the relevant bits of HTML and changed the code I'm trying - it's not working though - the image isn't changing in the browser :S

Answer (score 2):

If it's :

```
<img src="someimage.jpg" id="bg" />
```

Then it's :

```
$('#bg').attr('src', 'backgrounds/night.jpg')
```

Answer (score 1):

You should probably use

```
$('#bg')
```

instead of

```
$('#bg img')
```

in the second case, you are selecting all the IMG elements wherever UNDER the element #bg.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another more functional solution for your problem:

```
$("#bg").attr("src", function(i, value) {
    var src = "backgrounds/";

    if (hours > 20 || hours < 5) src += "night.jpg";
    else if (hours > 17) src += "dusk.jpg";
    else if (hours > 8) src += "day.jpg";
    else src += "dawn.jpg";

    return src;
});
```

And yes, you have to use `#bg` selector, since this is image itself.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#bg').attr('src', function() {
    var src = 'backgrounds/dawn.jpg';
    if (hours > 20 || hours < 5) {
        src = 'backgrounds/night.jpg';
    } else if (hours > 17) {
        src = 'backgrounds/dusk.jpg';
    } else if (hours > 8) {
        src = 'backgrounds/day.jpg';
    }
    return src;
})
```

Comment: I've changed how I'm doing it now, and edited my code with the changes people have suggested, but it still isn't working - any ideas?